# Wildfly multiple war files implement one interface: How to get implementations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, wildfly

I have an Interface and several war file which contain a specific implementation. Is there a way i can Inject the List of the implementations?

I only know the OSGI way, but is this also possible on JEE/Wildfly environment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following:
The jar file containing the api is configured as global dependency in wildfly (module) and the war files bind itself to an List which is reachable via jndi.